# Creating simple login form using Qt creator without any QtQuickControls

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, qml

I am new to Qt Creator . I want to build a simple form( example a Login form)
with a submit button in qml but without using any import QtQuick.Controls. How to create buttons using Rectangle component? ( that is using Qt Quick-Basic )

Can any one help with these?

Comment: Close voters:  Please read the tags under this question before close voting. The `qml` tag excerpt says: *Questions related to the development of QML applications on the Ubuntu environment. QML is a core programming language for Ubuntu & Ubuntu Touch.* This is an Ubuntu-specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for the above question:

Following is the code:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle{
    id:screen
    color: "lightgray"
    width: 3000; height:2700

    Column {
        id: column1
        width: 201
        height: 400

        Row {
            id: row1
            width: 40
            height:50

            TextInput {
                id: userName
                x: 40
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                text: qsTr("UserName")
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle1
                x: 115
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"
            }


        }

        Row {
            id: row2
            width: 40
            height: 50

            TextInput {
                id: password
                x: 40
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                text: qsTr("Password")
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle2
                x: 115
                y: 18
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"
            }
        }

        Row {
            id: row3
            x: 8
            y: 113
            width: 40
            height: 50

            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle3
                x: 8
                y: 8
                width: 80
                height: 20
                color: "#ffffff"

            Text {
                id: login
                text: "Login"
                x:4
                y:4
                width:30
                height:10
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone one help with headers file that is form.h and form.cpp? how should be the logic written for the above code?